# ASP.NET strange mp3 play

Tags: javascript, asp.net, flash

I'm using an ASP.NET server side control for playing mp3, of course I can use javascript or flash controls for doing so, but my problem is that I want the music to be played only once (at site start up), and its playing should continue when user displays new pages, I've used this control in master page, I don't want the music to be restarted whenever a new page is loaded, how can I solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames should generally be avoided, especially when it comes to layout. However, I think this is one case where a frame might be suitable since it ensures that the rest of your page can be refreshed without refreshing the frame page. The same can be achieved with AJAX, but I don't know how your site is structured and if it would require a huge rewrite to implement AJAX. So, you could create a small frame and have the music play from there. More information on frames and ASP.NET can be [found here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19435).

Comment: thanks dear friend, of course this comment is too late but I solved my long-lasting problem thanks to your answer, frames could solve my problem!